# Linux on hidpi displays: is scaling the only option?

Tags: xorg, display, dpi

I have a 210 dpi display. I noticed that in all desktop environments xorg forces the dpi to be just 96 and that I need to scale things x2 to be seen reasonably and fonts are being drawn with 192 dpi. As far as I know this implies two things:

1. Images and UI are being stretched so I don't get the actual resolution of the screen but something 2 times worse.
2. 210/96 is not an integer so fonts and images are not going to be as crisp as they could be.

Am I getting this right? In that case, what alternatives do I have to solve this?

Comment: You can set the dpi both upon start of X (details depend on your system) and with `xrandr -dpi 192`. However, not all programs actually react to the dpi settings, so results may vary according the program and libraries used. Specifically, I have no idea how and under what circumstances fonts will be scaled.